# component-wise multiplication for 3d vectors in windows store app programming

Tags: windows-8, directx, windows-store-apps, directx-11, directxmath

How to do component-wise multiplication of two 3d vector? it seems MS didn't provide such functions in DirectXMath.h, what's Microsoft doing there? in the old SDKs(DX 10/9), I can make a product of two vectors directly as:

v3 = v1 * v2;

or multiply a vector by a scalar like:

v2 = v1 * 1.0f;

but now, there is no operator * for XMVECTOR type, so I can't do that. so I need to make the product manually as

v3 = (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y + v1.z * v2.z);

although it is not so difficult, I think DirectXMath should provide such a basic function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dot product can be achieved with `XMVector*Dot` method. [MSDN link for dot3product](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/microsoft.directx_sdk.geometric.xmvector3dot%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

And the good page exists on msdn with methods list: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windows/desktop/ff729728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Also, I think that Microsoft didn't make operator* override because it is not clear which product this operator should use - dot or cross product.

Comment: thank you very much, I am sure I see XMVector3Dot, but in my mind the result of a  dot product is scalar(like what D3DXVec3Dot does), but now MS make the result as a vector. I didn't realize this change, so I missed this function.